# " Location " property in node/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, location

I have this code:

```
let stats;
if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    response.writeHead(302, {Location: "server.html"});
}
```

I don't know if  "Location"  is a javascript property or it only blongs to
Nodejs, and I can't understand it's usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `writeHead` function in Node just takes a javascript object, so in that sense "Location" is an arbitrary key in the js object. [writeHead documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers)

In terms of what values can go into that object and what they do, that's a general HTTP headers question. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Redirects) is some general info about headers and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) is info about location in particular.

about Location, Mozila developer network says:

The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to. It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201 (created) status response.
so in this case :

```
if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    response.writeHead(302, {Location: "server.html"});
}
```

when we enter some thing like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in the address bar it will automatically redirect to `server.html` so here "Location " defines redirection address.